# How do I set up a Kubernetes Ingress rule with a regex path?

Tags: regex, nginx, kubernetes

I'd like to use regex in the path of an Ingress rule, but I haven't been able to get it to work. [For example](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/examples/complete-example/cafe-ingress.yaml):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - cafe.example.com
    secretName: cafe-secret
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea
        backend:
          serviceName: tea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

I tried putting `/t[a-z]a` for the first path, but then any path I tried that should match that regex took me to the default backend instead of the service I expected.

Note: I'm using an nginx ingress controller, which should be able to support regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently this question is still getting traffic, so I feel like I should update it. I'm no longer using the nginx ingress, so I can't verify this works. According to https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/:

> The ingress controller supports **case insensitive** regular expressions in the `spec.rules.http.paths.path` field. This can be enabled by setting the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex` annotation to `true` (the default is false).

The example they provide on the page would cover it:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress-3
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo/bar/bar
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /foo/bar/[A-Z0-9]{3}
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

**Original answer that no longer works.**

It appears that the solution is ridiculously simple (at least with an nginx ingress controller) - you just need to prepend the path with `"~ "`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - cafe.example.com
    secretName: cafe-secret
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: ~ /t[a-z]a
        backend:
          serviceName: tea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Tried this solution today and it no longer works. Kubectl and the dashboard both say that Path must be an absolute string

Comment: @ChesterHusk yeah, a guy on my team noticed that a few days ago. I don't know if he figured out how to do it now, but please do add another answer to this question if you can figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Now you just need enable regexp by annotation:

```
annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

you can find full example [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an option to use regexp  in Ingress objects. Ingress is designed to work with multiple IngressController implementations, both provided by cloud services or by self-hosted ingress like nginx one from kubernetes/contrib (which I use on my setup). Thus ingress should cover features that are commonly available on most common implementations, while specific, non-standard behaviours can be set using annotations (like ie. many nginx ingress features).